# Is it possible to expose an enumeration as a class property?

Tags: php, enums, psr-4

I have a couple enumerations that are private to a particular class.  I originally had them in the same file as my class but, along with my confusion on PSR-4 autoloading, this was causing headaches.  In addition, it didn't seem to follow the PSR-4 spec (I think).  I can separate them into different files but for now, I don't particularly like that approach.  I'd prefer the code all be together.

```php
<?php

enum MODAL_SIZE {
    case SM;
    case DEFAULT;
    case LG;
    case XL;

    public function class() {
        return $this === MODAL_SIZE::DEFAULT ? '' : 'modal-' . strtolower($this->name);
    }
}

enum LAUNCH_TYPES {
    case BUTTON;
    case ANCHOR;
}

class modal {
    public LAUNCH_TYPES $launch_type;
    public MODAL_SIZE $size;

    // Implementation
    public function launcher(LAUNCH_TYPES $type = LAUNCH_TYPES::BUTTON, array $attrs = []) : string {
        // function's body
    }
}

$modal = new modal();

// error is thrown here
$modal->launcher($modal->launch_type::ANCHOR, ['text' => $rule[$label]])
```

My next thought is to simply expose the enumeration via the class as a property.  My editor seems to think this works as the autocomplete is as I would expect, however executing the code results in:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Typed property bootstrap\modal::$launch_type must not be accessed before initialization`

Am I being too picky here?  Right now, I have a single `modal.class.php` file under a directory named `bootstrap`.  I'd have to create a new subdirectory named `modal` and then have the `modal.class.php` file define the namespace as `bootstrap\modal` which would repeat the class name in my `use` statements.  Then separate files for each enumeration within the `bootstrap\modal` namespace/directory.

Comment: _"Typed property bootstrap\modal::$launch_type"_ - Is this really the code that throws this error? I don't see you trying to access that anywhere? Please check the error message (you can see which file and what lines the error is thrown in) and post the code that causes the error as well.

Comment: @M.Eriksson thank you for your comment.  I've updated the post to hopefully better depict what code is actually throwing the error.

Comment: A bit unrelated but your class and file names do not follow PSR-4: the class needs a leading uppercase letter and the file must be named with the class name (case sensitive) followed with `.php`, no `.class` etc.

Comment: _Opinion:_ Keeping all entities such as classes, enums etc in their own files with proper folder names that follows the namespace (PSR-4) is definitely something to strive for. It might feel excessive in the beginning, but you will realize the wins quite quickly (like using a [PSR-4 autoloader](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), removing the need to include classes manually and easier to find code since the file name says what it contains)

Comment: `$modal->launcher($modal->launch_type::ANCHOR, ....)` - This is where the error is thrown. Your declaration: `public LAUNCH_TYPES $launch_types;` doesn't actually _set_ the property. The `LAUNCH_TYPES` is only saying that the property can only contain a value of the type `LAUNCH_TYPES`. And since you don't have any default value, you can't read from that property until it's set.

Comment: @M.Eriksson You said "removing the need to include classes manually"...  Are you saying that the PSR-4 autoloader would remove the necessity of `use` statements at the top of files that need to consume a class/enum?

Comment: Well, using `use` isn't a _necessity_ since you don't _have to_ use them. You could use all classes full namespaces instead. `use` is just a way to import a class to your current namespace. So you can write `$foo = new Bar()` instead of `$foo = new \Full\Namespace\To\Bar()`, which makes it easier to read and you can replace one class with another by simply changing the `use` statemen in the top. It has nothing to do with including files or autoloading. I also don't really see the point of trying to store an enum in a class property like you're trying (which I don't _think_ you can do, tbh)

Comment: Its mostly about encapsulation I suppose.  I come from a background of JavaScript which I think is making me think about this incorrectly.  It doesn't help that there's another autoloader active in my environment that doesn't conform to any kind of PSR.  So I often get confused about the formats for each and which autoloader is actually finding my classes/files.  Thank you very much for your input.  I think you're correct also that the answer to my actual question is no.

Comment: If you want to assert a relation between your class and your enum, why not simply have them share the namespace. Instead of bundling into the same file or adding as enum as property. As noted, your error stems from `launcher($modal->launch_type::ANCHOR` (where you both refer to an uninitialized property and attempt to use it like an enum). Rather, use `launcher(LAUNCH_TYPES::ANCHOR`. Note that `public LAUNCH_TYPES $launch_type`, the property type declaration as enum means _you can store one of the values of that enum in `$launch_type`_, but **not that you "duplicate" the whole `enum` there**.

Comment: To reiterate. *It's fine to declare class property type as enum*. If you do that, _the value of the property can only be one of that enum's cases._ However, _having a "whole enum" as a property_ is the equivalent of _having a static class as a property_. There's no reason to do that, even if it were somehow possible. Enums and static classes are state agnostic, unlike instantiated objects that are commonly assigned to properties that are type-declared with the object's class.